# NLTK: How to keep reference to original text

Tags: nltk

I want to take a text

- run tokenization, stopwords, remove, lemmas and other analysis
- and then print paragraphs that fulfill certain criteria / score

However the steps above drop information / tokens. How do I keep the reference to the original text, so that I know where those elements originally showed up, so that can quote the correct paragraph?

Comment: You can wrap your text data in bean.

Comment: what is bean? Cannot find anything about it...

Comment: make a class with alignment indices per word. then you can extract the context you want from the index boundaries. one variable can store the unchanged text, another with the modifications, another for alignment indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in your corpus, split it up into paragraphs, and apply further processing to one paragraph at a time. Use the nltk's `PlaintextCorpusReader` to read your text and you can have the paragraphs, each already tokenized into sentences and words, simply by calling the `paras()` method. Here's an example using the `gutenberg` corpus (an instance of `PlaintextCorpusReader`).

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
tagged_paras = [ nltk.pos_tag_sents(par) for par in gutenberg.paras() ]
```